# Is there a min_id equivalent for max_id in rtweet's get_timeline?

Tags: twitter, rtweet

I'm using the twitter api and setting it up to collect Twitter information regularly. I'd like to avoid collecting tweets that I already have for a given user. I know that rtweet's max_id function allows you to collect only tweets *older* than a given id; is there a way to collect tweets that are *newer* than a given id number?